# Ionic 2 Multiple Menus on Multiple pages not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building a tabbed application in Ionic 2 which has five tabs one being the home page. The tabs work fine. I am trying to add a menu for each tab page other than the home page. I have duplicated and added the code below for each of the 4 pages in the home page just changing the menu id;s and the content id's. Everything works fine for the first page I access the subsequent pages I access just don't do anything. I thought this would be quite simple but already have spent days looking for a solution. The docs just refer to different menus on one page not different menus on several pages. Newbie so guess its simple. Help please.

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="dark">
  <button ion-button menuToggle="menujoinus">
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title>JOIN US</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-menu [content]="joinuscontent" id="menujoinus">
<ion-content> 
<ion-list> 
    <button ion-button block icon-right color="secondary"   menuClose="menujoinus">Close
    <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-item icon-left (click)="openPageFieldguides()">
        <ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon>
        Field Guides 
    </button> 
    <button ion-item icon-left (click)="openPageVolunteers()">
        <ion-icon name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
        Volunteers 
    </button>
    <button ion-item icon-left (click)="openPageOwner()">
        <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon>
        Owners
    </button> 
  </ion-list>
  </ion-content> 
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-nav #joinuscontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing but you need to add all the menus to the app component - not any of the sub pages - and then reference whichever you need from the sub page using the MenuController. In some cases you may need to disable/enable menus on the sub page but depends on the situation. Take a look at http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/MenuController/ and the "Multiple Menus on the Same Side" and "Multiple Menus on Different Sides" for more information.

An example:

```
<!-- Menu 1 -->
<ion-menu id="menu-one" [content]="nav">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Menu 1</ion-title>  
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item (click)="doSomething()" menuClose>
        Item 1
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item (click)="doSomething()" menuClose>
        Item 2
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!-- Menu 2 -->
<ion-menu id="menu-two" [content]="nav">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>  
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item (click)="doSomething()" menuClose>
        Item 1
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item (click)="doSomething()" menuClose>
        Item 2
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav #nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

And on the sub page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-page',
  templateUrl: 'sub-page.html'
})
export class SubPage {

  constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
    // menuCtrl.enable(false, 'menu-one');
    menuCtrl.enable(true, 'menu-two');    
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.toggle();
  }
}
```

The gotcha is the doSomething() method needs to be on the app component, not the sub page component.